# ADB Connection Error: Unable to create debug bridge

Tags: android-studio, adb

On starting recently fresh installed android studio bumblebee 2021.1.1 patch 2 I get an ADB running error which hereby I attach its screenshot. Please someone tell me what is the problem? I implemented all solutions given to similar cases in stackoverflow without any success.
[ADB Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BeFm.png)

```
ADB Connection Error
Unable to create Debug Bridge: Timed out attempting to connect to adb* 
* daemon not running; stating now at tcpc5037
* daemon stated successfully
Connected to adb for device monitoring
Sending Tracking request failed!
Adb connection Error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.
```

Comment: Do you try to connect to a device via USB or the new pairing method via network/TCP?

Comment: @Robert its not related to connected devices. this error shows up in AS start up.